Retrieve file path in Android and iOS using ReactNative
I'm developing a ReactNative project (android & iOS apps) under Expo management. I've already implemented a chat system where I should send and receive PDF file/Videos/Images and where I should retrieve the real file path from the gallery, needed to copy the file in app private area.
I got no problem with images and video using launchImageLibrary from 'react-native-image-picker' like this:
const openImageGallery = async () => {
        
        launchImageLibrary(
            {
                mediaType: 'photo',
                quality: 1
            },
            (response) => {
                if (!response.didCancel && !response.error) {
                    
                    const selectedImage = response.assets[0].uri;
                    const allowedExtensions = ['bmp', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'svg', 'tiff'];
                    const fileExtension = selectedImage.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

                    if(allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
                        
                        setAttachedFile(selectedImage);
                        setAttachedFileType('image');
                    }
                    else {

                        Alert.alert(
                            t('chatSendPhotoFormatNotSupported'),
                            t('chatSendPhotoSupportedFiles')
                        );
                    } 
                }
            }
        );
    };

and video equivalent. My problems starts when I need to select PDF file in Android: the only way I find is using DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker' but I can only gather the contentUri, not the real path, no problem instead with iOS.
I read many articles on how to translate contentURI to real path name but maybe I miss something... permissions maybe, but seems everything ok in my Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries> 

Thanks in advance!

You should not need "the real path" to "copy the file in app private area".
